# How to display random string from list on click in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script in my Script Editor:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [ {name:"Reach out",functionName:"reachout"} ];
  sheet.addMenu("Script", entries);
};

function reachout() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var cell = sheet.getRange("C3");
  cell.setValue(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",RANDBETWEEN(2,11))));
};
```

This script gives me the error: ReferenceError: "INDIRECT" is not defined

I have also inserted an Image in spreadsheet and attached the "reachout" function to it. But when i click on that image, i get "Function not found" error. Any hint would be a great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the function using `setFormula()`. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula

Please modify your script as follows.

**From :**

```
cell.setValue(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",RANDBETWEEN(2,11))));
```

**To :**

```
cell.setFormula('INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",RANDBETWEEN(2,11)))');
```

For 2nd question, when you give a function to an image, please set `reachout`. It's not `reachout()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please tell me exactly what script should i attach to Image? As I have just inserted whole "reachout" function and it says 
"cell.setFormula('INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",RANDBETWEEN(2,11)))'); could not be found"

Comment: You can see a small inverted triangle at the top right side on the image. Please click it and select Assign script. Please set the function name as ``reachout``. It's not ``reachout()``. I confirmed that it works fine.

Comment: that worked like a charm! awesome thanks a lot ! is it possible to copy to clipboard that "random string" we return from reachout function ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no methods to copy to clipboard using GAS. I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike